# disable textbox date in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery

I have seen that whatever date is in textbox it gets highlighted jquery date pickder

is it possible to disable same date in jquery date pickder

Thanks

Comment: @VinodVT its the default feature of jquery date picker it gets  highlighted if any date is there in textbox otherwise it highlights current date

Answer (score 1):

try this solution to disabled date, that is display in textbox

```js
      var array = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#detepickerId").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
            },
            onSelect: function (dateText, instance) {
                var dateSplit = dateText.split('/');
                array = dateSplit[2] + "-" + dateSplit[1] + "-" + dateSplit[0];
            }
        });
    });
```